# Can't read serial data: read() is waiting indefinitely

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I am trying to read / write serial data on linux using c programming. I can successfully open the port and set the attributes. But when I try to read the serial data, `read()` system call is waiting indefinitely. Can't understand why this is happening.

For testing serial communication I am using an arduino with 9600 baud and 8N1 configuration.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <errno.h>

int init(char *port);
void reads(int fd);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int fd;

    fd = init(argv[1]);

    fprintf(stdout, "\n\n####### DATA ########\n\n");
    reads(fd);

    close(fd);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int init(char *port){
    int fd;
    struct termios topt;

    fd = open(port, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);
    if(fd < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "init error: can't open port %s\n!", port);
        exit(1);
    }

    if(tcgetattr(fd, &topt) < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "init error: can't get terios attributes!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    topt.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;
    topt.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL;
    topt.c_cflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
    topt.c_cflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
    topt.c_cflag &= ~OPOST;

    cfsetispeed(&topt, B9600);
    cfsetospeed(&topt, B9600);

    topt.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    topt.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    topt.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    topt.c_cflag |= CS8;

    topt.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    topt.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;

    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &topt);
    if(tcsetattr(fd, TCSAFLUSH, &topt) < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "init error: can't set attributes!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void reads(int fd){
    char rdbuff[1];

    while(read(fd, rdbuff, 1) > 0){
        fprintf(stdout, "%c", rdbuff[0]);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `fprintf(stdout, "%c", rdbuff[0]);`. `stout` is line buffered. That is, no output will go to the terminal until a newline is seen. Try adding an `fflush` after the `fprintf`.

Comment: In arduino side code I have used `Serial.println()` function which automatyically adds a newline each time. Also tried using fflush(stdout), didn't work.

Ref: [println()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Println)

Comment: Oh, your `init` function is not returning the file descriptor! Your compiler should have warned you about that.

Comment: Ahhh! And I am digging for an hour! `gcc serial.c -o serial` didn't complain! Should have used `-Wall` flag!

Comment: Encountering another problem. I am sending "hello, world!\n" from arduino every 200ms. So my code should print stream of "hello, world!\n" in the terminal continuously. But its only printing 3 or 4 characters! sometimes 1 or 2 lines! Why is this happening?

Comment: Removed the `O_NONBLOCK` mode, added `O_NOCTTY`, set `c_cc[VMIN] = 1`. This solved the problem.

Yet don't know what is wrong with `O_NONBLOCK`.

Comment: `O_NONBLOCK` means nonblocking mode. If the read or write cannot be immediately performed (there is no serial data for `read()`, or the small serial hardware buffer is full for `write()`), they will return `-1` with `errno == EAGAIN` or `errno == EWOULDBLOCK`. It is only used when you need to do many things, and you wish to multiplex between those different things without being "blocked" at some `read()` or `write()` just because they cannot be performed *right now*.

Comment: Also, with serial (or networking stuff, for that matter), you should never, ever, assume that `read(fd, data, n)` or `write(fd, data, n)` returns either an error or `n`; they can, and will, often return some positive integer smaller than `n` (but not 0; they return `-1` with `errno==EINTR||errno==EAGAIN||errno==EWOULDBLOCK` instead in that case). These are called *short counts*. With serial or network reads and writes, you should always use a loop that reads/writes the rest of the data, if a call returns a short count.

Comment: when compiling. always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99`

Comment: the posted code produces a lot of warnings, many of which are: 'warning: negative integer implicity converted to unsigned type [-Wsign-conversion]'

Comment: Never access beyond `argv[0]` with out first checking `argc` to assure the desired parameter actually exists.   When it does not exist, output a 'usage' statement to stderr and exit the program.

Comment: the calls to `cfsetispeed()` and `cfsetospeed()` are being performed before the call to `tcsetattr()` so the speed values are being overlayed with the original/default speed values.  Suggest moving the calls to `cfset?speed()` to after the calls to `tcsetattr()`

Comment: the code should restore the original input/output speeds before exiting.

Comment: the returned/status value from each call to a system function should be checked to assure the function was successful.

Comment: it is always a bad idea to `#include` header files those contents are not used:  I.E. `string.h` and `errno.h`

Comment: the `init()` function signature states that it returns a `int`, but no such 'return' statement exists in the function.

Comment: So what should I do to read / write in non-blocking mode?

@NominalAnimal

Comment: @AshfaqurRahman: in non-blocking mode, you use [select()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) or [poll()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) to find which descriptors have data to be read, or can be written to without blocking. I guess I could spin up an example of a small program that does this, by writing data read from standard input to the serial port, and data read from the serial port to standard output, with the terminal in raw mode (each keypress sent immediately), if there is interest in such.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: It will be really helpful if you do that. Actually I have read [The Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](https://www.cmrr.umn.edu/%7Estrupp/serial.html) and [Serial Programming Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming) for Serial I/O or Terminal I/O. But still this topic is not clear to me. Could you suggest me a good book on this topic?

Thanks!

Comment: @AshfaqurRahman: I seem to have misplaced my Teensy 2.0 microcontrollers, which I like to use for this kind of testing. I don't have any tested code ready, and no serial devices to test, so I'm reluctant to post code I cannot really test. Terminals do behave almost identically, but I really prefer to use real hardware for this kind of thing. As to books, I'm afraid I just don't know; other than the serial port settings (`struct termios` fields), and especially how to use the various handshaking forms especially older devices use, I haven't needed anything outside man-pages.